# .php file blank - .php5 files works

Tags: php, php5, files

I have a problem with a server of mine. I've installed virtualmin/webin on it for administration and I have 1 domain on it. DNS management is external. On this domain I only have an html "Under Construction" index and 5 subdomains.

In all those subdomains I have PHP systems running perfectly. I've tried to install Wordpress on the main domain and I'm having some issues: None `.php` files loads. I have made a `phpinfo` file on it to check it and it won't work either; only a blank page appears. When I check the source code of it in browser, appears the code. I have changed the extensions to `.php5` and it worked perfectly. Something is going wrong with it but I can't figure out what.

I have checked the apache error and nothing appears. 3 Days ago I upgraded from `php 5.2.*` to `5.4.21`. Server is running CentOS 5.10.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding an handler in your vhost with the following type :

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php php
```

Be sure your default vhost is set with `ServerName default`.

Restart apache2.

Of course check the logs if anything happens.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have done what you suggested but it didn't do the trick. This is the [httpd.conf](http://albmania.com/httpd.conf.txt). I'm missing something but i can't figure out what :(

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using apache, check your configuration. On CentOS you likely have a file `/etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf` and in that file should be a line `AddHandler php5-script .php`

If that line doesn't exist, add that line and gracefully restart apache and try again.

It may be the line was changed to .php5 which you could just change to .php or add another line with the .php to allow both.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work :( . I have added that line and the problem was not resolved. Interesting is that this is happening only in root of the domain. All subdomains, existents or new created working perfectly :(

Comment: Can you show us what the wrapper script looks like? `/home/domain/fcgi-bin/php5.fcgi`

Comment: Also, do you have any .htaccess file hiding in your documentroot?

Comment: This is php5.fcgi: 
`#!/bin/bash
PHPRC=$PWD/../etc/php5
export PHPRC
umask 022
export PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN
PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS=99999
export PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS
SCRIPT_FILENAME=$PATH_TRANSLATED
export SCRIPT_FILENAME
exec /usr/bin/php-cgi
`
And...no, i don't have any .htaccess in document root :/

Comment: In your httpd.conf you linked, you have a pair of AddHandlers and then a set of RemoveHandlers, and another set inside the /dav directory. I'm not sure the purpose of the first set of RemoveHandlers, but try commenting those two RemoveHandlers and test again.

Comment: My only other suggestion is to try changing to CGI instead of FCGI for the main domain in virtualmin under Website Options.

Comment: I have commented those lines but no success. How to change to cgi? I'll check the virtualmin options to change it and let you know.
Thank you!

Comment: No success. When i passed it to CGI and accessing the php file, it offers me for download :-/

Comment: Hmmm...looking around, i found that subdomains are runing as mod_php and not as fCGid (Apache mod_php (run as Apache's user)). Does it count?

Comment: That could be related, maybe something is broken with the fcgi setup. mod_php is the "standard" plain way of running php as the apache user. If you don't need the benefits of (f)cgi you could run the main domain as mod_php and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried many and many ways to resolve it and i didn't :( so i have unistalled httpd and all php 5.4 and i reinstalled httpd/apache and php 5.3.27. Now, everything works perfect. Probably i break something on upgrade.
Thank you for your replies and for trying to help me.
All the best

Answer (score 0):

Notice that this applies to **virtualmin**/**webmin** php upgrade setup for **CGI**/**FastCGI**(fcgid).

Problem: After upgrade PHP to a newer version, browser only shows white screen/blank page for `.php` file; but works properly for `.php5` file.

**Solution**: http://www.virtualmin.com/node/25521#comment-115238

> On Ubuntu 10.04 I had updated PHP to 5.4.13 and then experienced the
>   very same symptoms that you've described.
>
> Disabling php5_cgi finally did the trick!
>
> Actually php5_cgi.conf also
>   includes that `SetHandler application/x-httpd-php` line which needs to
>   be commented out.

P.S. I haven't test on Ubuntu.

This method works on CentOS.
Delete line `SetHandler application/x-httpd-php` in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf`.